# Why does redirection fail in this case using RewriteCond & RewriteRule?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Why does following work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index11
RewriteRule (.+) https://www.google.com/
```

But following does not?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(index11)
RewriteRule (.+) https://www.google.com/
```

`former case` successfully redirects to `google.com` when I request `www.example.com/index11` but same `URL` doesn't work with `later case`

Comment: `index11` is "if index11 appears ANYWHERE in the uri". `^index11` is "if index11 appears at the START of the uri".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `%{REQUEST_URI}` also matches a `/` at start, so this will work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index11)
RewriteRule (.+) https://www.google.com/
```

Or this:

```
RewriteRule ^index11 https://www.google.com/
```